# Declaring an array in java as an object?

Tags: java, arrays

I have recently been following some tutorials on how to program and whilst programming the `public static void` for an array, the tutorial said to declare the array as an object. Below is the code for the array and at the end of the code I have put a split between the two sections so it is visible to as where my question lies

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class LoginList
{
int arraySize=500;
Login[] arrayLogin=new Login[arraySize];
int nextPosition=0;
int LoginLocation=-1;


public void addLogin(Login tempLoginParameters)
{
    arrayLogin[nextPosition] = tempLoginParameters;
    nextPosition++;
}


public void writeLogins()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedWriter LoginWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LoginDetails.txt"));
        for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
        {
            LoginWriter.write(arrayLogin[i].toString());
            LoginWriter.newLine();
        }
        LoginWriter.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error with writer");
    }
}


public void readLogins()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader LoginReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LoginDetails.txt"));
        String ReadLine = LoginReader.readLine();

        while(ReadLine!= null)
        {
            String[] arrayStringLogin = ReadLine.split(", ");
            Login tempLogin = new Login();
            tempLogin.UserName = arrayStringLogin[0];
            tempLogin.Password = arrayStringLogin[1];
            arrayLogin[nextPosition] = tempLogin;
            nextPosition++;
            ReadLine = LoginReader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error with reader");
    }
}


public void displayLoginDetails()
{
    for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Login "+nextPosition+": "+arrayLogin[i].toString());
    }
}


public void searchLogins(String TempLog)
{
    LoginLocation=-1;

    for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
    {
        if(arrayLogin[i].UserName.equals(TempLog))
        {
            System.out.println("Match At Position:"+i);
            LoginLocation=i;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("No match for UserName");
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LoginList ll = new LoginList(); //Declares the array as an object
```

Why is it that you have to declare the array as an object? Look just above here.

```
    Login tempLogin = new Login();
    ll.readLogins();
    ll.displayLoginDetails();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LoginList is not an array, it's a class that happens to have an array of Login objects as one of its instance members. The code in main creates an object of type LoginList and calls its methods; the LoginList object uses an array internally, but the main method doesn't have to know about it.